# Java - Get JSON Object Array?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to get the information listed at http://status.mojang.com/check with Java.
I understand that it's JSON so I've tried to get that information using varoius examples on the internet but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/USYy93kZ

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Try using the below method in your class to Parse the JSON.

```
private static String readAll(BufferedReader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    String cp = new String();

    while((cp=rd.readLine())!=null){

        sb.append(cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }


public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));


      String jsonText = readAll(rd);

      JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonText);

      //System.out.println(arr.toString(2));

      return arr;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }


 public JSONArray go() throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONArray json = readJsonFromUrl("http://www.comparestructuredproducts.com/AppData.aspx");

        return json;



      }
```